# strip fllename from path for copying list of files in zsh

Tags: for-loop, zsh, filenames, cp

In zsh, I want to copy each of the named files in a list of full paths to those same file names (without their full paths) in a stated directory . What's wrong with this:

```
fnames="/opt/local/etc/apache2/httpd.conf /opt/local/etc/php74/php.ini"
for f in ${fnames}; do cp ${f} ~/Downloads/${f}:t; done
```

The error I get is:

```
cp: /opt/local/etc/apache2/httpd.conf /opt/local/etc/php74/php.ini: No such file or directory
```

What I want to do is copy `/opt/local/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` to `~/Downloads/httpd.conf` and then to copy `/opt/local/etc/php74/php.ini` to `~/Downloads/php.ini` in this short sample command. (In practice, `fnames` will be longer, hence my wanting to loop over the list of names.)

(Please be gentle: I'm new at such zsh scripting!)

Comment: Think I just figured out how to do it. The key is that I do *not* need to strip off the filename from the path. Just this: `for f in $(echo "$fnames"); do cp ${f} ~/Downloads; done`

Answer (score 1):

In my view, there are two problems:

1 - The array must be:

```
fnames=(/opt/local/etc/apache2/httpd.conf /opt/local/etc/php74/php.ini)
```

2 - To get just the file name with no path use:

```
${f:t}
```

Instead of

```
${f}:t
```

Comment: I prefer the method in my comment to my original post, in that I still use a string rather than an array and can avoid any use of `:t` to strip off filenames from paths. Is there any advantage in going the array route instead?